# Is there a way to duplicate dependencies but with suffixes/prefixes added in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What I start with is:

```
foo: bar baz

baz: bar
```

and I want to automatically generate this:

```
foo-suffix: bar-suffix baz-suffix

baz-suffix: bar-suffix
```

and for all those dependencies to be considered by a call to `make`.

Is there a way to do that within a `makefile` without having to resort to an external script to generate the dependencies with suffix?

I have previously relied on writing a script that takes the output of `make -qprR` but it would be nice if there's a way to do this directly in a makefile.

Comment: Can you modify the original makefile? Where does it come from?

Comment: I am able to modify the original makefile but I don't want to manually duplicate the dependencies with prefixes/suffixes. The dependencies may be changed (removed, added, etc.) by an assortment of folks who may forget do make the same change for the prefixed/suffixed versions. The makefile already exists in an existing project